# Keeping essential config/configure files hidden on public Github forks

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I wish to fork a Github project that has config/configure files within it.

How can I run it alongside my desktop and live website project. But ensure that my config/configure files used on my desktop and live website (with all my db usernames etc) never get accidently copied/pushed over?

Answer (score 0):

this is about envoronment setting. what i saw before is one can have different settings of config in the same location and the program can use an environment variable to determine what configs to be loaded. In addition, confidential settings should be saved in env variable instead of github. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `.gitignore` file.

> If you create a file in your repository named `.gitignore`, Git uses it to determine which files and directories to ignore, before you make a commit.

Read more [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/).